# How can I show the Result with the trigger that I created?

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning-web-components, soql, sosl

So, I'm studying Apex Triggers in Salesforce with a practical exercise. As long as I was developing the exercise, I thought at my logical code, but when I tested the components, I had a problem with the trigger, when I create the rating.

How can I fix this bug?

**Expected Test**
The expected test is: when I put the followen input fields and show the grade that it has more votes. Like the screenshot below:
[image]

**Observed Bug**
[image]

**Line codes below**

Lightning Web Component - HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card  title="Rating List" icon-name="standard:display_text">

        <div class="average">
            <h6>Grade Average</h6>
            <h1 name="average">{acc.Rating}</h1>
        </div>

        <template if:true={ratingMetadataWire.data}>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr style="width: 100%; display: flex; padding: 20px; justify-content: space-between; align-items: flex-start; text-align: justify;">
                        <th  style="width: 100%">
                            <span>{title}</span>
                        </th>
                        <th  style="width: 100%">
                            <span>{descr}</span>
                        </th>
                        <th  style="width: 100%">
                            <span>{grade}</span>
                        </th>
                        <th  style="width: 100%">
                            <span>{author}</span>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <template for:each={ratingDataList} for:item="data">
                        <tr key={data.Id} style="width: 100%; display: flex; padding: 20px; justify-content: space-between; align-items: flex-start; text-align: justify;">
                            <td style="width: 100%">
                                <span style="display: flex; text-align: left; align-items:left;">{data.Name}</span>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 100%">         
                                <span style="display: flex; text-align: left; align-items:left;">{data.Description__c}</span>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 100%">
                                <span style="display: flex; text-align: left; align-items:left;">{data.Grades__c}</span>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 100%">
                                <span style="display: flex; text-align: left; align-items:left;">{data.Author__c}</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </template>
                </tbody>

            </table>
        </template>

    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Lightning Web Component - JS

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import getRatingList from '@salesforce/apex/RatingListController.getRatingList';



export default class RatingList extends LightningElement {

    @track ratingDataList;

    @api recordId;

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: 'Rating__c'})
    ratingMetadataWire;

    @wire( getRatingList, { accId: '$recordId' })
    generateRatingList({data, error}){
        data ? this.ratingDataList = data : console.log("Error: ", error);
    }

    
    get title(){
        return this.ratingMetadataWire ? this.ratingMetadataWire.data.fields.Name.label : '';
    }

    get descr(){
        return this.ratingMetadataWire ? this.ratingMetadataWire.data.fields.Description__c.label : '';
    }

    get grade(){
        return this.ratingMetadataWire ? this.ratingMetadataWire.data.fields.Grades__c.label : '';
    }

    get author(){
        return this.ratingMetadataWire ? this.ratingMetadataWire.data.fields.Author__c.label : '';
    }

}
```

Apex Clas => Rating List Controller

```
public with sharing class RatingListController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Rating__c> getRatingList(String accId) {
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Description__c, Grades__c, Author__r.Name FROM Rating__c WHERE Account__c =: accId];
    }
}
```

Apex Trigger

```
trigger ratingTrigger on Rating__c (after insert) {

    List<Rating__c> ratings = [SELECT Id, Grades__c FROM Rating__c];
    List<String> gradeList = new List<String>();

    Account acc = [SELECT Id FROM Account];
    
    Integer good = 0;
    Integer medi = 0;
    Integer bad = 0;

    //search for each analysis at the list
    for(Rating__c rating : ratings) {
        gradeList.add(rating.Grades__c);

        if(rating.Grades__c.equals('Good')){
            good++;
        }
        else if (rating.Grades__c.equals('Medium')){
            medi++;
        }
        else {
            bad++;
        }
    }

    //verify how many counts of each grade has on the Account
    if((good >= medi) && (good >= bad)){
        acc.Rating = 'Good';
    }

    else if ((medi >= good) && (medi >= bad)){
        acc.Rating = 'Medium';
    }

    else {
        acc.Rating = 'Bad';
    }    

    insert acc;
}
```

Comment: What is the bug? Please **[edit]** your post to clarify expected vs. observed behavior.

Comment: Done! I clarified the post, @AdrianLarson .

Answer (score 0):

You are querying Account as a single sObject (`Account acc = [SELECT Id FROM Account];`
) instead of a list of sObjects, which can lead to either a `List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject` or a `List has no rows for assignment to SObject` exceptions. Either you use a [list of records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_list_sobject.htm) which is recommended as best practice, or filter your query enough to assure one Account will always be returned.

You are also inserting an Account that already exists, which will fail with a `INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call`. Instead you should update it or create a new Account and insert that one instead, depending on your objective.

Comment: It's like this?
`List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id FROM Account]´ ?

So I can list all the Accounts and put at the forEach loop...

Comment: @TioFeliz if you want to update them all, yes. You should then iterate over the records and update accList at the end. If you want to update only one then you should keep your code as-is (besides `insert acc;` that should be `update acc;` and either include `LIMIT 1` in your query or make it specific enough so that it only returns one result.